# How to store regex "literals" in Postgres?

Tags: regex, postgresql

I want to store regex pattern/option "literals" in a Postgres database, like:

```
/<pattern>/options
```

I think it's helpful to indicate the expected format and use of the text. Also, the application framework I'm using can coerce this kind of text into the proper `Regex` type.

I looked through the [data types](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype.html) and provided [extensions](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/contrib.html) and didn't see anything specific. Am I missing one?

If there is no specialized type, is there a *reasonable* way to constrain TEXT to *likely* contain a regex (not to validate the regex, just to ensure text between forward-slashes). Does this work?

```
pattern TEXT CONSTRAINT is_regex (pattern LIKE '/%/%')
```

---

At the moment, I'm only using these literals in application code, which is why the TEXT to `Regex` transformation is very helpful. At some point, I might get better at CTEs and transform them *back* to regular TEXT (without forward-slashes or options) to be used in Postgres [pattern matching functions](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-matching.html).

Comment: Why do you think you need forward slashes? `a*` is a valid regex. And a regex is just characters, so I don't see why `text` wouldn't be appropriate.

Comment: Regex patterns are just strings of characters. What's preventing you from just storing them as `TEXT`?

Comment: I guess because people are going to use the API and I want to provide _some_ indication that `pattern TEXT` is meant to be a regex pattern and not just any old text. Also, it helps coerce the text into a regexp type in my application framework.

Comment: You can keep saying they're just strings of characters, but so are IP addresses and timestamps and arrays... except when they're not and we can do much better. Can't you read the question and understand the context? Help me write a better title if that's your problem.

Comment: With IP addresses and timestamps, there are storage formats with significant space advantages over text; and for time stamps, also arithmetic. I don't see this for a regex. What you might consider, if compilation of regex is a major time drain on your application, is storing them in the compiled form relevant to your application (e.g., Python byte code; SPITBOL pattern object) as a BLOB. I really doubt this will be helpful, but it will be unusual!

Comment: IP addresses, timestamps, and arrays are **not** strings of characters. They all have different storage formats (an IPv4 address, for example, is four 8-bit integers, or simply one 32-bit integer) that can be _represented_ as a string of characters. A regex pattern, on the other hand, is almost universally stored and represented as plain text. You could go the BLOB route like Andrew Lazarus says, but depending on how you are implementing the API that executes the pattern it might be non-trivial to actually use that BLOB after you've pulled it and I can't imagine you would get any real benefit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PostgreSQL doesn't offer such type (as of now), but generally speaking you have a few options to preserve database integrity (I can only assume you want this to avoid worrying that the data you read from the database fails your application, because it's not a valid regular expression).

Your best bet is (which you already figured out) is to use a `CHECK` constraint, one way or the other. If you plan to use this *pattern* in multiple places, I suggest you to use [domain types](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/domains.html). That way, you don't have to define these constraints at multiple columns. Ironically the best way to write such a `CHECK` constraint is to write a regexp pattern to match *your* regexp patterns (because there are multiple regexp implementations with slight differences). It obviously won't be perfect, but it might be good enough. I.e.

```sql
create domain likely_regexp as text
    check (value ~ '^/([^/]*(\\/[^/]*)*[^\\])?/[a-z]*$');
```

But if you're okay to check against PostgreSQL's implementation, you can (ab)use the fact that `CHECK` constraints fails not only when the evaluated expression is `false`, but they also fail when the expression throws (raises) some error. So you can call a regexp function in order to detect if it's actually a valid regular expression or not. Altough you still have to split the pattern and the options part.

```sql
create domain pg_regexp as text
    check (regexp_replace('', replace(substring(value from '^/(.*)/'), '\/', '/'),
                          '', substring(value from '/([^/]*)$')) = '');
```

https://rextester.com/YFG18381